# SQL Server get random rows depending on the column's sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, dynamic

For example, I have this table in my SQL Server database :

| Document | NumberPageMax |
| --- | --- |
| First | 48 |
| Second | 12 |
| Third | 4 |
| Fourth | 8 |
| Fifth | 1 |
| Sixth | 3 |

I need to get a random list of Document for whose the sum of NumberPageMax is equals to 50. If it's not possible to have exactly 50, it's ok to have a little more (first and sixth document for example to have 51).

Do you know if it's possible to do that in SQL and how ?

Thank you !

Comment: This seems an algorithm question and thus the sizes matter.  How many documents do you have in the actual problem, and what is the actual sum you are targeting?  I am assuming this table is just an example and your actual data are larger than this.

Comment: In addition, do you need to find the strict optimum (the smallest possible sum greater than or equal to 50) or is approximation acceptable?

Comment: This is a bin-packing problem, and is NP-Hard. You need to find an algorithm to implement, make a start at implementing and come back here if you need more help. It's far too complex for a single [so] answer